# Grafana Panel Error about height and width

Tags: grafana, grafana-templating

I am working on build grafana dashboards for my project.

I have facing the issue that some of my panels keep shows "Invalid dimensions for plot, width = 415, height = 0"

I am not sure how to fix it.  I tried to increase the size of the graph, however the table always there.

I really appreciate your help.

The screenshot is below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TmFm.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZu9L.png)

Comment: Which panel type did you use?

Comment: I am using the graph Panel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just increase height of your graph panels in the UI - make them higher (or disable legend, so there will be space for graph). See example of the same panels with different heights:

[image]

Click on the mark in the right bottom corner and change height of the panel.

Comment: Hi Jan, I am not sure where I can increase the height in the UI? Do you mean edit it?

Comment: I mean, I set the legend option to show as table.  But I am not sure how to decrease the size of the table and be able to increase the graph height.

Comment: Hey Jan, I tried and still not work.  Since the table always hide the graph.I just update the pics on the question.

Comment: 1.) remove table = disable legend or 2.) make panel higher, so there will be space for legend and graph

Comment: Hey Jan, I removed table, but I keep "show option" and the legend is on top of the graph.  Is there a way for me to keep the legend and the graph?

Comment: No, you query returns too many series, so you need extra space for legend for stats for all time series.

Comment: Hi Jan, you are right and I also realized it is better to use table instead. But thanks for your help.